# Prove that following sequence is bounded

Tags: calculus

I have to prove that $x_n=\frac{1-n}{\sqrt{2+n^2}}$ sequence is bounded. I've solved some easier ones, but these seems to be kinda different. I have to find actual bounds of the sequence.

Comment: Hint: $(x_n)$ is bounded if and only if $(x_n^2)$ is bounded.

Comment: It is convergent, hence bounded.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $x_1=0$ and $x_n<0$ for $n>1$

Answer (score 0):

**Lower bound:** 
$$ \frac{1-n}{\sqrt{2+n^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+n^2}} - \frac{n}{\sqrt{2+n^2}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+n^2}} - \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+n^2}} - 1 > -1$$

**Upper bound:**
Since $\sqrt{2+n^2} > 0$ we get

$$\frac{1-n}{\sqrt{2+n^2}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+n^2}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Upper bound : $U=1/√2;$

$n=0$: $x_0= 1/√2$;

$x_1=0$; and $x_n <0$ for $n \ge 2$;

Let $n \ge 2$:

$\dfrac{2-n}{\sqrt{2+n^2}} >\dfrac{-n}{\sqrt{2+n^2}}>$

$\dfrac{-n}{\sqrt{n^2}}=\dfrac{-n}{n}=-1$;

Lower bound: $L=-1$.

Comment: but $n$ is natural only.

Comment: jolskey. $n=0,1,2,.....$ natural numbers.  $x_n$ can be positive, xero, and negative depending on $n$.Ok?